# how can I figure out what is wrong with my system

Tags: windows-vista, hardware-failure, virus, compaq-laptop

I have a laptop that is running vista. its a compaq with 2gb ram 1.7ghz single core processor...as of lately it does not want to run anything right...if I download a file on it the system will not allow me to open it I get a quick timer icon to show it wanted to do something but it just disapears.some applications will allow me to open them if they were downloaded from another computer but often get random errors about the system not being supported.The clock date and time will not stay synced properly I have to manually adjust time then update it over internet to get it right. and it will not update with windows only nist...I have installed a number of antivirus softwares run a scan and then removed each one afterwards but no virus has been detected by mbam afg or any others...some other issues I have noticed include the audio will make a bit of a click noise at boot and the screen will flicker a couple times at boot including a point where a white line will flash for a breif moment but then afterwards the system appears perfectly stable excepting the bugs mentioned.I have gone ad far as reinstalling the os from scratch but the problems return even after updating all drivers in various orders.ie manufacturer vs window distributed software

first is it possible that some sort of virus could have imbedded itself in my equiptment somehow that these softwares are not designed to detect (ie a ramdisk or in the drivers of a disk drive or the processor itself).

second is there something I may not have thought of besides what I fear most(that my hardware is dying and I will need to replace the whole unit soon)?

Comment: There are endless possible explanations; malware would be low on my list.  Aging hardware (even multiple issues), is a good bet. Test the hard drive.  Sometimes retail drivers have problems with OEM hardware (go back to OEM drivers as a test, especially video).  The system has minimal resources by today's standards and part of the problem could simply be that it can't handle what you are trying to run on it now.  Troubleshooting will require methodical testing to diagnose and rule out possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

A Compaq laptop running Vista sounds pretty old.

This sounds like hardware failure. I would, at a minimum, boot up a memtest86 CD and fully test your RAM.

Comment: not sure if I used that exact tool but pretty sure I used one like it from ultimate boot cd did read and write and math tests and came back fine...